# How call procedure from another class

Tags: java, android

Hello please help me with call

```
    package com.paradox02.dell.dormation01;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Movie;
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;


    public class GifView2 extends View{



    public void Load2() {

        int riad = 0;
        switch (riad) {
            case 0:
                Obr0();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 1:
                Obr1();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 2:
                Obr2();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 3:
                Obr3();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 4:
                Obr4();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 5:
                Obr5();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 6:
                Obr6();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 7:
                Obr7();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 8:
                Obr8();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 9:
                Obr9();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 10:
                Obr10();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 11:
                Obr11();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 12:
                Obr12();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 13:
                Obr13();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 14:
                Obr14();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 15:
                Obr15();
                riad++;
                break;
            case 16:
                Obr16();
                riad++;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

I need launch procedure Load2 in another activity (On start in index activity)

but I don't know how.

or, please give mi some links where I can read about this problem.

Or give mi advice for another solution my problem.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: `new GifView2().Load2()` ?

Comment: new GifView2().Load2();

Error:(24, 9) error: no suitable constructor found for GifView2(no arguments)
constructor GifView2.GifView2(Context) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor GifView2.GifView2(Context,AttributeSet) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor GifView2.GifView2(Context,AttributeSet,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: and, how parameters i need? 

and where?

Comment: I try shared on google and try look for my problem on Andorid 4.0 book. but.. nothing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following constructors to your `GifView2` class:

```
public GifView2 (Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public GifView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

Then, in your index `Acitivty` class (assuming your class does extend `Activity`, or `AppCompatActivity`, etc.:

`new GifView2(this).Load2();`